# Upper bound sum of entries of a vector in terms of L2 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

Consider a vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with entries $x_i$. Given that $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_2\le n$, and no other information, what is the best possible upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ that we can have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and check that it is tight.

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n 1^2} = \sqrt{n}\|x\|_2$$ Equality holds when $x_1=\cdots=x_n$.